# iOS NSMutableArray initial custom object

Tags: ios, objective-c, model, nsmutablearray

How can I initial custom object ?

I have many Point data, so I create the Point data Object(class) like below:

MyPoint.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface MyPoint : NSObject

 @property (assign, nonatomic) NSString*  pointName;
 @property (assign, nonatomic) NSString*  lat;
 @property (assign, nonatomic) NSString*  lng;

 @end
```

Then the data will composite many area, so I create other object in the MyArea.h

```
 #import "MyPoint.h"

 @interface MyArea : NSObject


@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString*  areaName;

 @property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray<MyPoint*> *myPoint; // --1

 @end
```

How to initial the myPoint in my MyArea.m ?

I not sure which declare is right in below:

```
 @property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray<MyPoint*> *myPoint;
```

or

```
 @property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray<MyPoint> *myPoint;
```

And How can I create the NSMutableArray with my custom object(MyPoint) in the .m file.

In the MyArea.m

```
 #import "MyArea.h"

 @implementation MyArea

 -(id) init{
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
         self.myPoint = [NSMutableArray<MyPoint*> new ];  // ??
   }
     return self;
 }
 @end
```

Have any one can teach me how to create the model in the objective-c.

I will get a lot of data then set in to the MyArea object.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what exactly is not working? It fail to see the problem

Comment: Your second option for the `myPoint` property declaration is the correct on. Remember, it is an `NSMutableArray` pointer that containers pointers to `MyPoint` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom initWithPoints:(NSMutableArray)points.

For example:

```
- (instanceType)initWithPoints:(NSMutableArray<MyPoint *> *)points
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        NSLog(@"_init: %@", self);
        self.myPoint = points
    }
    return self;
}
```